# A doubt regarding Russell's paradox.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a doubt regarding [Russell's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

We know that the collection of sets not containing themselves is not a set. Hence, let that collection be a class $\mathcal{A}$.

Does this imply that $\mathcal{A}$ cannot contain itself? Because if it does, then it will be a set not containing itself (as it is inside $\mathcal{A}$), which is a contradiction as we just stated that $\mathcal{A}$ is not a set.

Thank you.

Comment: As $\mathcal{A}$ is a proper class, it cannot be an element of any class. Only sets can be elements of classes.

Comment: $\in\ne\subset$.

Answer (score 3):

By your definition, $\mathcal{A}$ is the *collection* of *sets* that do not contain themselves.  Also, you have acknowledged that $\mathcal{A}$ is *not a set*.

Since $\mathcal{A}$ contains only sets and $\mathcal{A}$ is not a set, then no, it cannot contain itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working in NBG or ML or something, $\mathcal{A}$ is a *proper class* that doesn't contain itself. Theories with proper classes only let you form collections of those classes which are sets. Here, Russel's paradox proves that $\mathcal{A}$ is not a set, so it doesn't even match the defining condition of $\mathcal{A}$ in the first place.

If you're working in ZFC, there's simply no such thing as $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: So what $\mathcal{A}$ is in reality is the class of all sets not containing themselves? In ZFC, I assume.

Comment: Yes, it is the class of sets that don't contain themselves. Though there's an important point in $ZFC$ that $\mathcal{A}$ doesn't exist as a set or class internally to the theory. More precisely, none of the quantifiers of ZFC range over any such thing as $\{x: \exists y(x\in y)\wedge x\notin x\}$.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of modern set theory, a proper class is not an element of another class. In other words, if $X$ is a class, and there is some $Y$ such that $X\in Y$, then $X$ is a set.

Since we already know that $\{A\mid A\notin A\}$ is not a set, it cannot be an element of another class, let alone of itself.